# How should I move the camera position correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I want to move the camera position to make the object appear smaller, but if I set a larger z value, the object disappears.
eg:cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 800), and then the coin will disappear.
I'm a SceneKit newbie and would appreciate some help, thanks!
Or can you introduce a SceneKit tutorial based on SwiftUI?

```
import Foundation
import SceneKit

class CoinFlipGameScene: SCNScene{
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        createCoinNode()
        setUpCamera()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


extension CoinFlipGameScene{
    
    func createCoinNode(){
        let coinGeometry = SCNBox(width: 100, height: 100, length: 0, chamferRadius: 0)
        
        let coinHeadMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        coinHeadMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "coin-head")
        
        let coinTailMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        coinTailMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "coin-tail")

        coinGeometry.materials = [coinHeadMaterial, coinHeadMaterial, coinTailMaterial]
        
        let coinNode = SCNNode(geometry: coinGeometry)
        coinNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        self.rootNode.addChildNode(coinNode)
    }
    
    func setUpCamera(){
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 100)

        self.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct CoinFlipView: View {
    
    var scene: SCNScene{
        let scene = CoinFlipGameScene()
        
        return scene
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        SceneView(scene: scene, options: [.allowsCameraControl])
            .background(.clear)
    }
}

struct CoinFlipView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CoinFlipView()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfhU9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by adjusting the [`SCNCamera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera) instance's [`zFar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1436596-zfar) property, or by enabling [`automaticallyAdjustsZRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1436610-automaticallyadjustszrange).